# Serverless (AWS) – CORS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, serverless

I've built a lambda using Severless on AWS to parse a Base64 image into a file and upload it to an S3 Bucket.

Locally and via Postman, everything works as expected but I'm having CORS issues on the browser at both `localhost` and tunneled to a https domain via ngrok. I've referred to [this guide](https://www.serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide) and numerous gists / repos many times but I've still had no luck.

I'm returning a response with headers as instructed:

```js
function response(statusCode, bodyJson) {
  return {
    statusCode: statusCode,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(bodyJson),
  };
}

module.exports.handler = (event, ctx, cb) => {
...

return cb(null, response(200, { message: "File Uploaded!" }));

}
```

serverless.yml for reference:

```yml
service: sendittojeff

package:
  individually: true

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

custom:
  bucket: sendittojeff-images

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: us-east-1
  profile: default
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - "s3:*"
      Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.bucket}/*

functions:
  uploadImage:
    handler: uploadImage.handler
    environment:
      Bucket: ${self:custom.bucket}
    events:
      - http:
          path: uploadImage
          method: post
          cors:
            origin: "*"
            headers:
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              - X-Amz-Security-Token
              - X-Amz-User-Agent
              - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
              - Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
            allowCredentials: false

resources:
  Resources:
    UploadBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.bucket}
        AccessControl: PublicRead
```

CURL Response via OPTIONS Method for the endpoint:

```bash
curl -v -X OPTIONS https://[**hidden**].execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/uploadImage

< HTTP/2 200
< date: Fri, 12 Feb 2021 03:19:05 GMT
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 0
< x-amzn-requestid: ab9e5d8b-cff2-49c5-9351-ce328626e4c4
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
< x-amz-apigw-id: [***hidden***]
< access-control-allow-methods: OPTIONS,POST
```

Lastly, I've tried hitting this endpoint via jquery's `$.post` method as well as via `fetch` from the browser in various configurations (headers, cors, etc..) with no luck.

Browser request and error response here:

```js
  fetch(
    "https://[***hidden**].execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/uploadImage",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: {
        image: dataString,
      },
    }
  )
```

With the `application/json` header included, a call to OPTIONS is made, as expected, with a returned status code of `200`. The POST request, however, only reads `CORS error`.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://[**hidden**].execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/uploadImage' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:4000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

POST https://[**hidden**]].execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/uploadImage net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: Provide the error detail what you get on your browser.

Comment: are you using api gateway?

Comment: I haven't setup / modified any settings outside of the serverless.yml file — as I understand this can get some things out of sync — but yes it does look like there is an API Gateway item setup for this endpoint.

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response to the POST request? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. If Chrome doesn’t show it to you, use the Network pane in Firefox devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: There's no status code shown for the POST request. It only reads 'CORS Error'. I'm not sending any headers.

The OPTIONS request shows a 200.

Comment: If there’s no HTTP status code shown for the POST request, then it’s possible the request isn’t actually reaching that AWS server at all, and so there’s no response for the browser to do anything with. If that were in fact the case, then the browser would still log a CORS error just like that one in the question. And if that were the case, it would mean there’s not necessarily any problem with the existing CORS config you’ve already set up on that server. Instead the problem could be that the request is getting canceled or blocked by a firewall, or a number of other possible things.

Comment: To get more help, you probably want to get into the Network pane in browser devtools, and copy all the request headers and response headers for the POST request, and paste them into the question. Otherwise, without seeing details for what’s happening with the request, and what kind of response is coming back, all that anybody here can do is just speculate and ask you more questions.